# app rejection due to IPv6 issue

Tags: ios, swift3, ipv6, submission

I recently got an iOS app rejected due to lack of `IPv6` compatibility.
After browsing the internet to investigate on the subject, I decided to view those two videos:

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/719/

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/714/

Now back to debugging the app, I am trying to follow what I can read here:
http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-how-to-test-your-app-for-ipv6-compatibility/

At one point in the document we can read:

*14. Once sharing is active, you should see a green status light and a label that says Internet Sharing: On. In the Wi-Fi menu, you will also see a small, faint arrow pointing up, indicating that Internet Sharing is enabled. You now have an IPv6 NAT64 network and can connect to it from other devices in order to test your app.*

This is where I hit a problem. In my case I can indeed see:

"**a green status light and a label that says Internet Sharing: On**"

But I do not see in the `Wi-Fi menu`:

"**a small, faint arrow pointing up, indicating that Internet Sharing is enabled**".

So my guess is that I must have either done something the wrong way or have a configuration not matching what is expected by this document.

I have also tried several choice for `Share your connection from:` but to no avail. In the same way, looking at my iPhone does not show any sign of new access point.

Any suggestion coming from an expert on the subject or someone with some experience would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sharing your thunderbolt connection, in order to be able to make an ipv6 wifi network, you would have to share your thunderbolt connection. basically you can no be both connected to wifi, and create a new wifi connection, hence that you need to have an lan/thunderbolt connection to share on your newly created wifi ipv6 network

Comment: There is only one right answer for "Share your connection from:" and that is your wired Internet connection.

Comment: OK. I get it. I will try using  a wired connection then and see.
Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I did the change suggested here in the comments, using a cable connection. Now I can use the Mac as a Hot-Spot and choose that connection point on my iPhone. But when I go to 
http://test-ipv6.com/ using the iPhone, it still seem to believe: "No IPv6 address detected". What is wrong here?

Comment: Well you created an IPv6 hotspot, but your outside connection is not IPv6, meaning that your hotspot network, uses IPv6, but the router, connecting it to the internet used IPv4, so when you exit your local network, going outside, to the internet, other sites (test-ipv6.com) will see your router IP which is IPv4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also recently encountered this issue when uploaded my previous apps to appstore.
The solution is used is - I recorded a video of app functioning  while connected to ipv6 network i.e. connected to any mobile hotspot. You just need to record this video and upload it on internet(generally i use google drive)  and make public link from it.

**Then in itunes, prepare for submission link, there is a section called add notes. In this section, you need to tell apple that your app is functioning properly under ipv6 network and tell them to check you video link.**
For sure, after doing these things as defined, Your app will be approved within 14 hours.
I now do these steps everytime i upload my new app.
Thanks

Comment: You mean that Apple's tests saying that my app does not run on IPv6 could be wrong?

Comment: Actually since I didn't see any problem when trying on my side I followed your advice. We'll see the result.

Comment: Yes, it could go wrong.
I know your app wil get approved, if followed my advice properly.
Please upvote my answer, if it resolves your query.

Comment: Indeed it did. Thanks!